# Perform segue from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, segue

I've been trying to perform a segue from a `UIBarButtonItem` (to be exact, it's a compose icon).

It's supposed to be a segue from a `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController`. I set up the connection by drawing a line from the `UITableViewController` to the `UITableView`.

I've also tried setting up the segue directly from the button, but that had no effect.

There aren't any issues when I run the application, but it just won't push the view. In fact, it doesn't even seem to reach the `IBAction` at all: I tried the button to also execute an `NSLog`, but it just doesn't show.

The connection in the .h file to the `UIBarButtonItem` can't be my mistake.

There are no gesture recognisers on my `UITableViewController` that could fetch the touch, either.

What have I missed?

I'd really appreciate help with this, for hours I've been trying to figure out my mistake, but this relatively small issue stops from trying out whether I did my own delegate messages. I'm really a beginner concerning Objective-C.

Thanks a lot!

PS:I've uoloaded two images to my dropbox here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mvmdx5eo380yg09/olyNaeauBA?v=1mci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the style from "push" to "modal"

"push" is used when you have a back button on next Navigation controller. Now you are opening a new controller (not a navigation controller with a back button) so you are going to use "modal"

Comment: Thanks, at least the button seems to have an effect now, but it crashes with the warning Receiver (<SelectionTableViewController: 0x8d7e530>) has no segue with identifier 'Compose'. The segue was drawn from the little yellow icon of the UITableViewController to the UIViewController. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the first picture on Dropbox I can see a segue with identifier "compose" in your code to the right. check that